# Сохраняются объекты класса в памяти при повторном их создании с тем же именем?

Tags: javascript, классы

Помогите разобраться.

Если у меня есть кнопка при нажатии на которую создается объект
`const newObj = new ObjectClass()`, который добавляет на страницу html.

При повторном нажатии кнопки создается еще один `const newObj = new ObjectClass()`.

Куда девается первый, так и остается висеть в памяти, или перезаписывается?

Comment: Зависит от конкретного кода

Comment: Если вы используете `const`, то получите ошибку, - константа не перезаписываема. Если другие области видимости, то, теоретически, перезаписывается. Фактически - во-первых, некоторые элементы экземпляра класса могут остаться в памяти. Скажем, перетечь в другое представление (в случае с отображением html) или просто остаться за наличием активных ссылок где-либо в коде (например, таймауты и интервалы будут работать, пока к ним не будет вызван clear). Во-вторых, ко всему экземпляру может быть где-нибудь активная ссылка.

Comment: что значит _добавляет на страницу html_?

Comment: Как всегда - без конкретного кода ничего нельзя сказать точно.

Comment: @Grundy класс содержит метод, который запускается в конструкторе и отдает html, что-то вроде компоненты реакт.

Comment: @AlexandrEinsteinov, добавь в вопрос [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

"Куда девается первый, так и остается висеть в памяти, или перезаписывается?"
Короткий ответ - собирается сборщиком мусора.
На хабре есть прекрасная статья на эту тему:
https://habr.com/ru/post/309318/

Если же вопрос лежит в другой плоскости и я Вас не правильно понял, то
замечу, что вот такой код вызовет ошибку:

```
{
   const  test = 'abc';
}

console.log(test);
```

Поскольку в функцию console.log мы передаем переменную, которую "не видно" - область видимости ограничена фигурными скобочками. Это можно назвать контекстом. Так вот, когда контекст более в программе не используется - в работу вступает сборщик мусора.